# select data from multible columns/tables and insert it into one column in View

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

i have 2 tables

TRACKING.SCALE1_LOG1_TAB

```
MTRL| WEIGHT10 
------------
   A| 10     
------------
   B| 11     
------------
   C| 9
```

AND
TRACKING_SCALE2_LOG2_TAB

```
MTRL| WEIGHT22 
------------
  M | 10     
------------
  W | 21     
------------
  X | 22
```

i need help with collection MTRL from table 1 and MTRL from table 2 into one column in a new view
and the same thing with WEIGHT column, Weight10 AND WEIGHT22 into column named WEIGHT in the view.

somthing like this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TRACKING.ALL_WEIGHTS_VIEW (MTRL, WEIGHT) as
(SELECT X.MTRL and Y.MTRL from X, Y tables),
(SELECT X.WEIGHT10 AND Y.WEIGHT22 from X,Y tables)
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, the "UNION ALL" is exactly what you need. Just create the view using the following

```
select mtrl, weight10 from TRACKING.SCALE1_LOG1_TAB
union all
select mtrl, weight22 from TRACKING_SCALE2_LOG2_TAB;
```